# React native not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I'm integrating my frontend with WebSockets when I get the message I set that into `const [messagesList, setMessagesList] = useState([])` state. But when I set the state and console it displays empty like `[]`.

I'm setting the state with this method:

`setMessagesList((messagesList)=>[...messagesList,{'msg':type,'user':data.text}])`

So how I can update the state with the previous array of data?

Comment: Why do you think that the state is not updating? Is the new message not rendering in the UI?

Comment: i didn't render currently I'm consoling it but on console it display empty []

Comment: you're probably logging right after calling `setMessagesList`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: yes i'm logging after calling